# Связь один ко многим MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
 id | city                  id | city_id | post_index
--------------            ----------------------------                   
1  | London                1  | 3       | 134679
2  | Amsterdam             2  | 1       | 23456-00
3  | Moscow                3  | 4       | 132-3556  
4  | New-York              4  | 4       | 434-6767 
5  | Praga                 5  | 4       | 345-1007
```

Как с помощью `T-SQL` получить таблицу
вида:

```
id | city        |   indexes   
--------------------------------------------                     
1  | London      |   23456-00            
2  | Amsterdam   |   Null(или пустая строка)         
3  | Moscow      |   134679       
4  | New-York    |   132-3556, 434-6767, 345-1007            
5  | Praga       |   Null(или пустая строка)
```

То есть значения `post_idndex` из таблицы 2 проставить в одну ячейку `indexes`,
вновь созданной таблицы 3, через запятую (например), тем городам где есть индексы в таблице.

Можете подсказать как написать процедуру или использовать другие возможности MS SQL, но было бы шикарно, если бы можно было сделать это одним запросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `FOR XML PATH('')`. Селект будет примерно такой:

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, 
 (SELECT i.post_index + ', ' 
 FROM cityindex i where i.city_id = c.id FOR XML PATH('')) as indexes
FROM city c
```